# Install rvm with rvm1-capistrano3 only if it is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I use `rvm1-capistrano3` in my project.

When I run `cap staging deploy`, I would like to install `rvm`, if there is no `rvm` installed.

But if there is `rvm`, I would like to skip this step.

How do I achieve it with `rvm1-capistrano3`?

Answer (score 1):

**For capistrano3** https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-capistrano3#install-rvm-1x

**For capistrano2** Use the install_rvm module. https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#modules

It will install rvm if it is not there and update if it is.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use `rvm-capistrano` as it is for `capistrano 2`, and I use `capistrano 3`

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. Updated the answer.

Comment: That is what I am currently using, but it installs `rvm` every time I run `cap rvm1:install:rvm` task regardless of whether I have `rvm` already or not.

Comment: Is it installing it or updating it? If I were to have rvm installed on my computer and then run the install command again, it would try to update it. The update and install command are exactly the same.